# Behaviour of withMVar and bracket_ different

Tags: haskell, concurrency, locking, output

This ensures mutual exclusion of actions:

```
do
  lock <- newMVar ()
  let atomicPrint = withMVar lock . const . print
  mapM_ (forkIO . atomicPrint) [['1'..'8'],['a'..'h']]
```

This doesn't:

```
do
  lock <- newMVar ()
  let atomicPrint x = bracket_ (takeMVar lock) (print x) (putMVar lock ())
  mapM_ (forkIO . atomicPrint) [['1'..'8'],['a'..'h']]
```

Can you explain why? By the definitions of withMVar and bracket_ on Hackage and equational reasoning I came to the conclusion that the two pieces of code should do the same. But running in GHCi proves me wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the order wrong; You are acquiring the lock and *immediately* releasing it; whereas [the signature says](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:bracket):

```
bracket_ 
    :: IO a  -- computation to run first ("acquire resource")
    -> IO b  -- computation to run last ("release resource")
    -> IO c  -- computation to run in-between
    -> IO c  -- returns the value from the in-between computation
```

so it should be:

```
bracket_ (takeMVar lock) (putMVar lock ()) $ print x
```